# File attachment is taking too much time when using React Drop zone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I am using the `react-dropzone` library to drag or select files from the browser.

I have the below component to let the user select multiple files. Everything works except that if the user chooses more files let say 2 or more files with size 1 MB, the selection of documents is taking time. If the number of files is more, the more time it takes to selected the user-selected files.
As per my reading of the `react-dropzone` docs, it processes files as soon as it uploads. So I tried setting  autoProcessQueue='false'.
but no luck.

I just want to let the user select all the files without blocking for 30 or 40 secs after selecting files, and before send to the backend server.
I did the debug and the setSelectedUserFiles() is reached after all the files are processed internally by the DropZone. I am not sure if there is a way to disable it and let it process as part final submission of the form or click on the button.
In case if we can't achieve the same, is there a way to show the message to the user that files are being attached.
Any help will be appreciated.

Below is my react component

```
const SelectUserFiles = () => {
  const [userName,setUserName] = userState('TestUser')
  const [selectedUserFiles,setSelectedUserFiles] = userState([])
 
  const handleUserFileUpload = async (acceptedFiles) => {
      await setSelectedUserFiles(acceptedFiles)
    }
  
  return (
    <div className='myClass'>Select Files</div>
      <Dropzone
        //autoProcessQueue='false'
        accept={'.pdf'}         
        onDrop={acceptedFiles => handleUserFileUpload(acceptedFiles)}
      >…</Dropzone>
    </div>
    
    <MyButton>
    //logic to send the files to backend axios with the files selectedUserFiles 
    </MyButton>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

1. Create separate api component that only send files,
2. Your component that has dropzone manages file upload
   locally without sending to the server. You only click the button
   and send it.
   this link was very helpful:
   https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

first component:

```
export const useApiCall = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    const [selectedAllUserFiles, setSelectedAllUserFiles] = useState([]);

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const pushToserver = async () => {
            setIsError(false);
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                const formData = new FormData();
                Array.from(selectedAllUserFiles).forEach((file) => {
                    form.append('fileData', file);
                });

                const result = await axios.post(someUrl, formData);

                setData(result.data);
            } catch (error) {
                setIsError(true);
            }

            setIsLoading(false);
        };
        if (selectedAllUserFiles.length > 0) {
            pushToserver();
        }
    }, [selectedAllUserFiles]);

    //passing reference to the calling component

    return [{ data, isLoading, isError }, setSelectedAllUserFiles];
};
```

Second component:

```
const SelectUserFiles = () => {
  const [userName,setUserName] = userState('TestUser')

  const [selectedUserFiles,setSelectedUserFiles] = userState([])

  //Ref from logical api call component
  const [{ data, isLoading, isError }, setSelectedAllUserFiles] = useApiCall();//new component

  const handleUserFileUpload = async (acceptedFiles) => {
        if (acceptedFiles) {
            acceptedFiles.map((file) => {
                setSelectedUserFiles((selectedUserFiles) => selectedUserFiles.concat(file));
                return selectedUserFiles;
            });
        }
      
      //await setSelectedUserFiles(acceptedFiles)
    }
  
  return (
    <div className='myClass'>Select Files</div>
      <Dropzone
        //autoProcessQueue='false'
        accept={'.pdf'}         
        onDrop={acceptedFiles => handleUserFileUpload(acceptedFiles)}
      >…</Dropzone>
    </div>
    
    //on click call api and pass collected user files all together
    <MyButton onClick={()=>setSelectedAllUserFiles(selectedUserFiles)}>
    //logic to send the files to backend axios with the files selectedUserFiles 
    </MyButton>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. But I am doing exactly the same. Not sending files to the server upon upload. I am storing in state and then when the user clicks on the button, I am making an API call with the files selected. Sorry if my question is not clear. The problem is with second component. It takes to attach multiple files and would like to see how I can show a progress when it takes time attache files using dropzone

Comment: I see. your problem is attachment of the file is taking time, not uploading. 1 MB should not be taking that much time, I tried with 3 MB image and it is fast, like 2 second. I tried with hook version of react-dropzone not component. May be you ca try that too. Can you also try image files see if only happens for pdf?

Comment: Thanks. yes. my question title says the problem with attachment. I will try useDropzone hook. 1MB is not a concern. In my use case, uploading 50 files at once with each file size is around 1 MB. This is not an issue of taking time, but how do I show the progress to the user so that they know what is happening